# Multiple Worksheet_Change Issue

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to have multiple `Worksheet_Change` in one sheet, however I'm having issues implementing them.

I tried:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Target.Address = "$B$6" Then
    Select Case Target.Value
      Case "Yes"
        Range("DataYes").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Range("DataNo").EntireRow.Hidden = False
      Case "No"
        Range("DataYes").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Range("DataNo").EntireRow.Hidden = True
      Case ""
        Range("DataYes").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Range("DataNo").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End Select
  End If


  If Target.Address = "$Q$6" Then
    Select Case Target.Value
      Case "TRUE"
        Range("DataNo").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Range("CrComments").EntireRow.Hidden = False
      Case "FALSE"
        Range("CrComments").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End Select
  End If

End Sub
```

In This case, only the first piece of code works. The second doesn't. No error messages.

I also tried:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Select Case Target.Address

  Case "$B$6"
        If Range("B6").Value = "Yes" Then
            Range("DataYes").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("DataNo").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ElseIf Range("B6").Value = "No" Then
            Range("DataYes").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("DataNo").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Range("B6").Value = "" Then
            Range("DataYes").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("DataNo").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
      End If

  Case "$Q$6"
        If Range("Q6").Value = "TRUE" Then
            Range("CrComments").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ElseIf Range("Q6").Value = "FALSE" Then
            Range("CrComments").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
      End If


End Select
End Sub
```

In This code, I got a `End if without block if` error for the last `End If` of the first case.

*Deleting the errored End IFs still doesn't make the second piece of code work*

Answer (score 2):

Cell values of "FALSE" and "TRUE" will be read as `False` and `True` (boolean values, not strings), so your test on Q6 needs to be changed.

```
If Target.Address = "$Q$6" Then
    Select Case Target.Value
      Case True
        Range("DataNo").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Range("CrComments").EntireRow.Hidden = False
      Case False
        Range("CrComments").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End Select
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a Cell from which it reads this string. And the cell is written as TRUE or FALSE. When I changed this part of the code, the `Q6` section still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You have two wrong "End If", here is the fixed code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Select Case Target.Address

      Case "$B$6"
            If Range("B6").Value = "Yes" Then
                Range("DataYes").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Range("DataNo").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            ElseIf Range("B6").Value = "No" Then
                Range("DataYes").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Range("DataNo").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            ElseIf Range("B6").Value = "" Then
                Range("DataYes").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Range("DataNo").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If

      Case "$Q$6"
            If Range("Q6").Value = "TRUE" Then
                Range("CrComments").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            ElseIf Range("Q6").Value = "FALSE" Then
                Range("CrComments").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

As for you original issue it should not change anything.

Could you provide more information please?

Comment: Thanks, I receive no errors, however the `Q6` Section still does not work. The `Q6` section is a cell that is changed to either `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on a checkbox selection. If it's true, a row should be unhidden. The `B6` section works, the `Q6` does not. Here's more code. `Option Explicit

Sub AssignRownames()

Rows("15:15").EntireRow.Name = "DataYes"
Rows("16:16").EntireRow.Name = "DataNo"

Rows("8:8").EntireRow.Name = "CrComments"

End Sub`

Comment: Even with the camel case? Anyway here is an empiric ninja tactic ;) : put a breakpoint at "If Range("Q6").Value = "TRUE" Then", then have a look at the value of "Range("Q6").Value" and you should know how exactly Excel is interpreting your input.

Comment: This is my first time debugging with excel. It will take a minute or two :)

Comment: Take your time, because in the future it will save you days ;)

Comment: Okay, here's what I did: `Dim MyRNG As Long
MyRNG = Range("Q6").Value`. When It's TRUE, I get -1. When It's false, I get `Out of Context`.

Comment: You should use another type than Long, like String or Boolean.

Comment: That's weird. I receive normal `"True"` and `"False"`. I have no idea why it's not working.

Comment: You may receive them due to automatic conversion when you do MyRNG = Range("Q6").Value; from here try to use this variable like this: "If MyRNG = "True" Then" instead of referencing the Q6 range value directly.

Comment: Did not work... Can I upload the document somewhere for you to see?

Comment: The error I have now is `Variable Not Defined`. This is what I have in the `Worksheet_Change` function: `Case "$Q$6"
            If MyRNG = "True" Then`

Comment: Because you should have this line somewhere above: "MyRNG = Range("Q6").Value" and if you are in explicit mode another "Dim MyRNG As String"

Comment: From you original code you may be more lucky with "Range("Q6").Text" which should be a string like "TRUE". Sorry but I have not an english version of Excel so can't test.

Comment: No Problem, I will keep on trying. Thanks!